# Unity and Linux

Tags: unity, linux

Is it slow to run unity with wine? And are there any plans for unity coming to the Linux platform. Since i now that it can create a build for Linux i wish it was coming for Linux as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion based and beyond that can only be answered with speculation.

Answer (score 2):

I dealt with this issue and found out that at the moment Unity3d is not coming on Linux.
I'm using Ubuntu Trusty Tar, running unity 5.02 with Wine under PlayOnLinux. It works perfectly.

I will quote you some instruction which can be easily found on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJsB32T9Spk)

> I used simple PlayOnLinux installation! Downloaded the Editor file for
>   Windows from the Unity site(I took 64-bit). Than I went in Play On
>   Linux, went to tools > Manage Wine versions and installed Wine 1.7.40
>   for both x64 and x86. Than I pressed install. On bottom left selected
>   the install non-listed program. Than I created new virtual drive
>   called Unity3D, selected the installation bits accorting to the Editor
>   downloaded(I took 64-bit). After that completed all installation and
>   made shortcut for Unity.exe. In here I downloaded quick icon, but now
>   I have set the original icon for it(RC shortcut(.desktop file) and
>   select icon(press on icon and choose one from your computer). It runs
>   for me. After that I selected the Unity icon in Play On Linux, pressed
>   configure, on the top selected section with additional packages,
>   installed the Microsoft Core Fonts so I can see text in Unity editor.
>   I also installed Standard Assets from the Unity site like
>   this:Download the .exe Open Play On Linux Install- Non-Listed program
>   Update existing virtual drive- Unity 3D Select Wine 1.7.40 Select the
>   Standard Assets file Install Done, it is installed, don't make any
>   shortcuts here, leave it as it is, run the Unity and enjoy;)

Comment: I would add that Unity version 5.x is [currently Gold on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32071), so it should run just fine.

Comment: I would also go check out the "suggested features" (IIRC) page on the Unity website. The most asked for feature is a Linux client, you might be able to find some tips there.